# How to return value of cell OFFSET relative to VLOOKUP result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to build an Excel formula which finds a specific cell in a table, and retrieves the value of another cell, that is offset from the frist cell by a specific distance.
In the table below you will see a list of languages and their associated costs. I am trying to create a formula whihc looks up the value of D1 in the table, and retreives the value of the cell that is 2 columns to the right and 3 rows down of that cell. In this specific example, I am trying to get the total cost of German, which is 27.5.

[Table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqjMr.jpg)

I dont understand why this formula does not work:
=OFFSET(VLOOKUP(F1, A1:C15, 3,FALSE), 3, 0)

The error message I am getting is: 
The formula you typed contains an error.

Comment: You got to look into Index + Match more so than offset and vlookup, while lookup is as fast as index-match at it's best, it's usually slower while offset is a volatile function meaning it will recalculate on worksheet changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Index/Match` instead:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$15,MATCH($F$1,$A$1:$A$15,0)+2)
```